# Android Studio: Json Parsing loads only 10 objects out of 50 that exists in the URL

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress, android-studio

I wrote a code that parses Json Data from my WordPress website and put it in a ListView, everything **works perfectly**, except the fact that it decided to load only 10 Json objects out of nearly 50 that exists in the URL. 
After going through over and over my code, and after I've tried everything, I am going to ask here what could be the problem.

This is my class, it is called "getJsondata"

```
 public ArrayList<GamesLibrary> getJsondata(String strurl)
{
    ArrayList<GamesLibrary>arrayList=new ArrayList<GamesLibrary>();
    String line="";
    String res="";
    InputStream in=null;
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
            URL myURL = new URL(strurl);
            URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
            in = ucon.getInputStream();
            Log.d("Negev", in.toString());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("asaf",e.getMessage());
        }


        BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"iso-8859-1"));

        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        String input;

        while((input=br .readLine())!=null)
        {
            b.append(input+"\n");
        }

        in.close();
        br.close();


        try
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(b.toString());
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {

                Log.d("asaf","try json"+i);
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = json_data.getString("title");
                String content = json_data.getString("content");
                String content2 = content.replace("\\n", "");
                String content3 = Html.fromHtml(content2).toString();
                String content4 = content3.replace("\",\"protected\":false}", "");
                String title2 = title.replace("{\"rendered\"", "");
                title2 = title2.replace("\"}", "");
                title2 = title2.replace("\"", "");
                title2 = title2.replace(":", "");
                title2 = title2.replace("Date", "");
                String id = json_data.getString("id");
                String slug = json_data.getString("slug");
                GamesLibrary gamesLibrary= new GamesLibrary(Integer.valueOf(id),title2,content4,slug);
                arrayList.add(gamesLibrary);
                Log.d("ff",content3 );

            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {

        }
        return arrayList;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return null;
}
```

The code works perfectly, but loads only 10 posts, why is that do you think?
Thank you!

Update:
The arraylist contains only 10 objects, the problem is that it should contain nearly 50...

Update 2: exact Json: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wkuAFZWn1jF-_7AO_zvrI4mo1V6paUODvaUW8TAn03k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: do you see the 50 items when you go to the URL ?

Comment: Does your method return 10 items, or ListView displays 10. Can you debug your method return statement, what that returns ?

Comment: Yes I do see 50 items in the URL, and the ListView is perefectly normal, so I don't think the problem is with the list view... and thank you!

Comment: Yes I checked, the listview can load more than 10 objects...

Comment: return arrayList;

When you debug this, how much elements does it contain ? 10 ?

Comment: Yes I made a Log that shows me the size of the arraylist, and it returned 10.

Comment: I think I know what is the problem, can you post your exact json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your json, and it contains only 10 items :)

ids: 921, 919, 474 472 470 468  466 464  462 460

[image]

Comment: Hi I posted my exact Json, and I didn't understand what to do if there is a problem with the 11th item, and thanks!

Comment: Hah, I found what was problem, see my updated answer. There were no exceptions :)

Comment: Hi my bad, I posted the wrong Json! this one doesn't suppose to have 10... No, the original one does have 10 either, wow I feel so stupid, Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't worry, it happens :) 

שיהיה לך יום טוב